# Why is one equation solution for the wave equation while the other isn't?

Tags: waves, wavefunction

Can someone explain why the equation $$y(x, t) = A \log(x + vt)$$ is a solution for the wave equation while $$ y(x, t) = x − 2$$ isn't? I just couldn't understand my professor explanation, he said I should make a partial derivative with $$\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial \:x^2}\left(y\left(x,\:t\right)\right)=\:\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial \:\:t^2}\left(y\left(x,\:t\right)\right)$$
Should I partially derive by $x$ and $t$ with the second equation and then compare it?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what the idea is to do. You'll find both sides equal to zero, so really you've made a "trivial" solution that does not evolve in time at all (so it's not really a wave, or it's like a wave with $v=0$).

Comment: So, since both partial derivative of x and t equal 0, the wave does not evolve in time. In conclusion, x-2 is not a solution for the wave equation, right?

Comment: Why not? 0=0 is a valid statement.

Comment: Please, explain. I'm lost again.

Answer (score 10):

It's a perfectly valid solution for the wave equation, since the second derivatives of $y(x,t) = x - 2$ with respect to $x$ and $t$ both vanish and the wave equation becomes $0 = 0$, which is [checks notes] true.

What may have confused your professor is that it's also true that all solutions to the wave equation in 1D are of the form
$$
y(x,t) = f(x - vt) + g(x + vt).
$$
The solution you proposed, $y(x,t) = x - 2$, doesn't immediately appear to be of this form.  But one can do some manipulation to put it in the canonical form.  Let $f(z) = g(z) = \frac12 z - 1$, and then
$$
f(x - vt) + g(x+vt) = \left[\frac{1}{2} (x - vt) - 1\right] + \left[\frac{1}{2} (x + vt) - 1\right]  = x - 2.
$$

Comment: @MichelSeifert has shown you that the second function is that of a (very) stationary wave.

Comment: @Farcher it is even more than that: it is a very stationary wave that results from the superposition of two waves travelling at arbitrary but equal speeds in opposite directions

Answer (score 5):

While the answer by Michael Seifert gives some mathematical explanation, I'd like to give a physical understanding of why the function

$$y(x,t)=x-2\tag1$$

is a solution of the wave equation.

Consider a string attached to a wall by two ends and tensioned. Apply a force in the middle point of the string, so that the string deflects. After the oscillations stop (due to friction, which we neglect in the wave equation), deflection of each side of the string will be described by $(1)$: both sides of the string will be straight.

Each side of the string can be described by the wave equation, since the force is only applied at a single point (that we exclude from equations' domains) and nowhere else. Thus, $(1)$ should indeed be a solution of the wave equation, which is exactly the equation of motion of a string.